# Column Positioning in Joins in the ON clause in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, left-join

I have a table which shows parents, children and their last name. I want to join the table to itself to see which child belongs to which parent. Normally I would use a left join to list all of the parents along with their matching children (as not every child has a parent in this table) however I am confused as to why my original query does not do this for me? If someone would be so kind to explain this that'd be fantastic

```
CREATE TABLE people(
pid int primary key,
childid int null,
lastname varchar(15)
)

INSERT INTO people VALUES(1, NULL,'Red')
INSERT INTO people VALUES(2, 1,'Smith')
INSERT INTO people VALUES(3, 1,'Anderson')
INSERT INTO people VALUES(4, 2,'Griggs')
INSERT INTO people VALUES(5, 3,'Noble')
```

Below is my original query that I thought would have done the trick

```
select p.lastname as Parent, c.lastname as Child
from people p
LEFT JOIN people c
on p.pid = c.childid
```

The results of this query:

```
+----------+-----------+
|  Parent  |   Child   |
+----------+-----------+
| Red      |  Smith    |
| Red      |  Anderson |
| Smith    |  Griggs   |
| Anderson |  Noble    |
| Griggs   |  (null)   |
| Noble    |  (null)   |
+----------+-----------+
```

However I get the result I want by using the query below

```
select p.lastname as Parent, c.lastname as Child
from people p
LEFT JOIN people c
on c.pid = p.childid
```

Results of this query:

```
+----------+----------+
|  Parent  |  Child   |
+----------+----------+
| Red      | (null)   |
| Smith    | Red      |
| Anderson | Red      |
| Griggs   | Smith    |
| Noble    | Anderson |
+----------+----------+
```

If someone can explain the difference to me why the results between the two queries are so different, it'd be a big help! Thanks

Comment: Just trace it out. In the first p.pid = c.childid and in the second c.pid = p.childid

Comment: In the first you are joining to `c.childid` so you are getting the children of `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have the parent and child roles transposed in your data schema and your query.  This is why the second query almost appears to work (you transposed them back though you mislabeled the answer).  The way your table is setup, every person can have only one child.  Where I believe you wanted to say that every person has a parent instead.  (I'm ignoring, for simplicity, that every person *should* have a mother and a father!).  I've changed your table DDL to reflect this (I've also made the naming a bit more explicit and explicitly declared the foreign key.)

```
CREATE TABLE people(
personid int primary key,
parentid int foreign key references people(personid) null,
lastname varchar(15)
)
```

Apply the same insert statements to this code.

I've also modified your first query as follows:

```
select p.lastname as Parent, c.lastname as Child
from people c
LEFT JOIN people p
on p.personid = c.parentid
```

I flipped the 'c' and 'p' references around.  This properly reflects the asymmetric left outer join being properly aligned with the asymmetric relationship between parent and child.

Executing this query will produce

```
+----------+----------+
|Parent    |Child     |
+----------+----------+
|NULL      |Red       |
|Red       |Smith     |
|Red       |Anderson  |
|Smith     |Griggs    |
|Anderson  |Noble     |
+----------+----------+
```

Notice that in your example the second query returns the correct relationships but it mis-labels them.  It says that Red has no child when it should say that Red has no parent.  This revised query corrects that.